# What does “watermarked the moon” mean?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

The English lyrics of the song "[A Requiem for Innocence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVU9DTg2oRg)", composed by Gao, from the soundtrack of the 2018 video game *The House in Fata Morgana: A Requiem for Innocence*, include the line “Watermarked the moon, cast the hex”. I don’t know what it means.

Even “cast the hex”, is it like “throw the witch” or “cast upon the witch a curse”?

This is more of the lyrics for context:

> No breathe in the wood,
> The oaks are dead, the elms are sunk,
> No faith shall save the witch
> Watermarked the moon, cast the hex

Comment: The use of "breathe" instead of "breath" in the first line invites suspicion that the writer of the lyric is either careless or not fully in command of the language. Having said that, I note that both "watermarked" and "cast" can be read as past-tense verbs, meaning that you might read the final two lines as "No faith shall save the witch / [who] Watermarked the moon and cast the hex" or as "No faith shall save the witch / [because] Watermarked [is] the moon and cast [is] the hex." These are, however, by no means the only possible interpretations of these very ambiguous lines.

Comment: @SvenYargs Good point, but maybe for the OP it's also necessary to point out that "watermarked" and "cast" can be participles, and "dead" and "sunk" already start that trend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Hex](https://www.google.com/search?q=hex%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsZA2wAbreE_5AF716v_67yirLYmYw%3A1660322834414&ei=EoT2YsDtGKa69u8Ph_6H0Aw&ved=0ahUKEwjAvofG4MH5AhUmnf0HHQf_AcoQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=hex%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgAELEDEEMyBQgAEJECMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQkQIyBAgAEEMyBQgAEJECMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAdKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFgAYIYEaABwAXgAgAFfiAFfkgEBMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)*** is a spell, and I am sure you know what ***[cast a spell](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cast-a-spell-on-over-someone)*** means.

As for ***watermark***, it means

> a design which is put into paper when it is made, and which you can only see if you hold the paper up to the light. Banknotes often have a watermark, to make them harder to copy illegally.([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/watermark))

Now, if you look at the moon it does seem it is watermarked with a mysterious design. However, one can't be sure if the author of this verse used the moon as a watermark, as a design to imprint on something as a logo, like:

[image]

or if he refers metaphorically to this watermarked-like complexion of the moon:

[image]

Comment: So it could mean: under the watermarked moon, we casted a spell..? Since moon is always related to casting spells.

Comment: Not excluded, since it is a rather dark poem... ("cast a spell", not *casted).